# Can't Execute a PHP file via HTTP

Tags: php

Here is a command I successfully execute in terminal:

```
PHP process_scan.php
```

I want to execute that code every time a user visits a file, which exists in the same directory as the file mentioned in the command.

Here is the code in the file:

```
exec('PHP process_scan.php 2>&1', $output, $retval);
```

Running the file in the browser, `$retval = 127` wit `$output = "sh: PHP: command not found"`.

How can I successfully run the command every time a user visits the file?

Comment: Try using the absolute pathname to the script. It's probably looking for it in the wrong folder.

Comment: To debug this, use `exec('PHP process_scan.php 2>&1', $output, $retval);` so that the error message will be in `$output`. The error message should show the reason for the error.

Comment: To debug this, use `exec('PHP process_scan.php 2>&1', $output, $retval);` so that the error message will be in `$output`. The error message should show the reason for the error.

Comment: I tried using the absolute pathname with no success. Using `2>&1` outputs `sh: PHP: command not found`

Comment: You'll need the full path to PHP, since it won't exist in the web server's path. `/usr/bin/php process_scan.php`

Comment: `exec` is a PHP System command so you're trying to run a PHP script from another PHP script which is loaded by a web browser? Therefore you should be able to run the remote script as an `include` without needing to explore the extremely unwise use of `exec` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing PHP, I got this to work by executing PHP bin file:

```
exec('/usr/bin/php process_scan.php 2>&1', $output, $retval);
```

Comment: Why do this instead of including it?

Comment: So that it can be run as a background task.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, this code executes process_scan.php in the foreground - the http task waits for the cli call to complete before responding… which is logically required if you are referring to the output or retval in any way at all.

Comment: Sounds very much like a https://xyproblem.info/